# Regular expression for HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, lex, lexical-analysis

I am working on Lexical Analyzer. I have an HTML file. I want to convert every letter in the file expect whatever written within an HTML tag into CAPITAL letter. Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
       StackOverFlow
    </body>
</html>
```

This will be converted to following.

```
<html>
    <body>
       STACKOVERFLOW
    </body>
</html>
```

I just want to know that regular expression that will select everything within HTML tags and do nothing to them.

Consider only simple HTML tags that are within `<` and `>`.

Comment: You could try `(?<=<)[^<]+(?=>)`. Or just match the brackets with tags: `<[^<]+>`.

Comment: I would try simply `<.*?>`, to match everything surrounded by angle brackets.  If you have an angle bracket in your non-html, though, this would fail.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati: Posted, please consider accepting.

Comment: The pony stirs in his dark cavern and eyes you all with infinite hunger. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why are you using RegExp for lexical analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either of the following regexes:

```
(?<=<)[^<]+(?=>)
```

*Explanation:* `(?<=<)` - check if we have a `<` (don't consume) before `[^<]+` (1 or more non-opening brackets) (consume), and then check if we have `>` after it with `(?=>)` (don't consume). Since we consume just the middle part, we have `p` instead of `<p>` as a match.

Or, just to match the brackets with tags:

```
<[^<]+>
```

*Explanation:* `<` matches a single literal `<`, then `[^<]+` matches 1 or more characters other than `<` and then a single literal `>`. All characters are consumed, thus, the match will look like `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the source of the input/audience of users, you may want to step up the tolerance. While I hate tag attributes without quotes, you do encounter that. You will also encounter lazy brackets in tags, like `value="4 > 3"`.

```
(?<=<)([\w-]+)((?:\s+[\w-]+\s*(?:=\s*(?:[^"'>\s]+|("|').*?\3))?)*)\s*(?=>)
```

or

```
<([\w-]+)((?:\s+[\w-]+\s*(?:=\s*(?:[^"'>\s]+|("|').*?\3))?)*)\s*>
```

Explanation of the first regex (the second is similar but actually captures the brackets rather than observing them with lookarounds).

```
 (?<=                              # Opens LB
     <                             # Literal <
 )                                 # Closes LB
 (                                 # Opens CG1
     [\w-]+                        # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                     # Token: \w (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                                     # Any of: -
                                     # + repeats one or more times
 )                                 # Closes CG1
 (                                 # Opens CG2
     (?:                           # Opens NCG
         \s+                       # Token: \s (white space)
         [\w-]+                    # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                     # Token: \w (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
                                     # Any of: -
         \s*                       # Token: \s (white space)
                                     # * repeats zero or more times
         (?:                       # Opens NCG
             =                     # Literal =
             \s*                   # Token: \s (white space)
             (?:                   # Opens NCG
                 [^"'>\s]+         # Negated Character class (excludes the characters within)
                                     # None of: "'>
                                     # Token: \s (white space)
             |                     # Alternation (NCG)
                 (                 # Opens CG3
                     "             # Literal "
                 |                 # Alternation (CG3)
                     '             # Literal '
                 )                 # Closes CG3
                 .*?               # . denotes any single character, except for newline
                                     # * repeats zero or more times
                                     # ? as few times as possible
                 \3                # A backreference to CG3
                                     # This is not a repeat of the match, not the pattern.
                                     # If this is an Octal Escape try padding with 0s like \003.
             )                     # Closes NCG
         )?                        # Closes NCG
                                     # ? repeats zero or one times
     )*                            # Closes NCG
 )                                 # Closes CG2
 \s*                               # Token: \s (white space)
 (?=                               # Opens LA
     >                             # Literal >
 )                                 # Closes LA
```